# How can I not show my public IP in Glances?

Tags: server, 20.04

Is there a option in the Glances system monitor that allows my public IP to be not shown with all the other stats? I couldn't find anything confirming or denying this - does anyone know?

Comment: Can you elaborate on hiding your IP? Do you mean hide it from other people, as in with a VPN/proxy/tunnel? Or as in not show it in a menu or display? I would assume the latter, but given the common usage of that term, I thought I would ask

Comment: @PixelatedFish I mean just not showing it on the display. Sorry! I'll make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't state how you're accessing the data, but assuming you're using the CLI, simply press `I` to hide your IP address. Note that this will hide your private address too; I don't believe there is a way to hide just one.

### UPDATE

I found the [docs link](https://glances.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glances.html?highlight=show%2Fhide#interactive-commands) that shows how to do this and some other UI-related stuff.